# Jquery hover out not working with .html

Tags: jquery, html

Im having trouble with a jquery function

working fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/kb9yn2kh/

```
<div class="menu">
  <h1>
    Menu
  </h1>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.menu').hover(function(){
   $(this).html('<h1>close</h1>')
 }, function(){
   $(this).html('<h1>menu</h1>')
})
```

basically im trying to change the inner html on hover and then change it back when you hover off, but I cant seem to get it to change on the hover off..

any help would be appreciated!

**Im aware there are similar questions but none that address .html()**

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by specifying a height property on your `.menu` element: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq8f8ztq/))

```
.menu {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Or instead of replacing the HTML element each time, you could just replace the text therein: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r27ewrsf/))

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('h1').text('close');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('h1').text('Menu');
});
```

Comment: Thanks giving `.menu` a height of 50px worked, but you have to go quite a bit far away for it to change back to menu, and when I change the value to `30px` for example It no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mouseover` and `mouseout` with children of the element.

```
  $('.menu').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('h1').text('close');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).children('h1').text('Menu');;
    });
```